# Is requests response likely to be corrupted?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using Python requests to play with a REST API. The response format is JSON and let's assume the server always send correct data. Given the fact that HTTP uses TCP for transmission, do I still have to check the existence of a required key if no exception is thrown by requests?

Comment: You should be able to rely on requests to provide you with the response your server sent back in an accurate form. I've never seen in my testing problems related to the module (that doesn't mean there arent bugs in it, I just didnt manage to run into them while doing "regular" stuff). That being said, I wouldn't rely on exceptions to validate a request answer, I'd implement my own logic, like checking the response code and then the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TCP transmissions, you don't need to verify the response if you assume that the server *always* sends correct data:

> TCP provides reliable, ordered, and error-checked delivery of a stream of octets between applications running on hosts communicating by an IP network.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

Of course, it's always a good idea to add some error handling and verification to your code just in case the server doesn't send what you'd expect.